# In c++ FAQ reference counting return value

Tags: c++

cited http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ref-count-simple.html

```
class Fred {
public:
  static FredPtr create();              // Defined below class FredPtr {...};
  static FredPtr create(int i, int j);  // Defined below class FredPtr {...};
  ...
private:
  Fred();
  Fred(int i, int j);
  ...
};

class FredPtr { /* ... */ };

inline FredPtr Fred::create()             { return new Fred(); }
inline FredPtr Fred::create(int i, int j) { return new Fred(i,j); }
```

How could new Fred() return FredPtr at the last two line code? I don't understand.

Comment: Because `FredPtr` contains a conversion constructor.

Comment: Implicit conversion. Look at the constructors for FredPtr.

Comment: What part of that FAQ entry which explains in great detail how this works are you struggling with?

Comment: I do not understand why people unnecessary down vote and even not take little pain of commenting reason.

Comment: @Brian, please quote to me the part of that FAQ entry that actually explains the matter of this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the link that you referenced, class FredPtr includes a custom constructor that takes a Fred*:  FredPtr(Fred* p).

The compiler knows that Fred::create returns a FredPtr.  It sees the return statement that calls new Fred (thus generating a Fred*), looks through the list of FredPtr constructors, and chooses the one that needs a Fred*... All is well.

Answer (score 0):

The line `new Fred();` returns a `Fred*`. `FredPtr` <del>probably</del> has a conversion constructor declared as `FredPtr(Fred*)`. This allows `FredPtr` objects to be created implicitly from `Fred*`.